# Why in vim is the first operand in move (m) 1-based and the last operand 0-based?

Tags: vim

Given the following file

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

When I say `:1m3`

the file looks like this

```
2
3
1
4
5
```

But when I say `:3m1` it looks like this

```
1
3
2
4
5
```

I thought the 3 should be before 1. Why is it like this?

Comment: Have you checked `:h :m`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no I have not. With this I am able to answer my own question. Thank you!

Comment: Please do. Answering one's own question is recommended here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stéphane Chazelas pointed out by using the vim help with `:h :m` it states the following:

```
:[range]m[ove] {address}                        *:m* *:mo* *:move* *E134*
                    Move the lines given by [range] to below the line
                    given by {address}.
```

Therefore by moving line 1 **below** line 3 the result is as stated in the question.
But if one wanted to move line 3 to the first line it has to be moved **below** line **0**

Answer (score 1):

Commands like `:copy` and `:move` put the target *below* the line given by `{address}`. You can use an address of `0` to move to the first line. Some commands (like `:put`) also support a reversal of before / after via `:put!`